# Does PayPal store recurring payments notify_url?

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have Google for almost 10 hours and it seems a bit unclear.

When I create a "Subscribe" button with my own "notify_url" will PayPal send an IPN to that URL when each recurring payment is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal won't store the notify_URL, you need to pass it everytime you send a transaction to paypal for processing.  Notify_URL is one of the attributes of the hash; so when paypal receives your transaction hash, it will pick up whatever values you set for each of the attribute and act accordingly.  Your understanding is correct!

Answer (score 2):

Paypal will use the same notify_url that you pass for every recurring payment on that same subscription. An example, may help.

If you pass a notify_url that contains the order id, like:
http://www.mydomain.com/paypal_ipn/{$order_id}

Then when somebody buys a subscription, Order #1, with a recurring payment for $1/day for a month, you will receive IPN data at "http://www.mydomain.com/paypal_ipn/1" for the initial 'txn_type=subscr_signup' and a 'txn_type=subscr_payment' every day until one of the following things occurs:

- the user cancels the subscription, at which time you will get a 'txn_type=subscr_canceled'
- their credit card expires 'txn_type=subscr_failed'
- a month later when the subscription expires 'txn_type=subscr_eot'

On the next order, Order #2, all the IPN calls for that subscription will go to "http://www.mydomain.com/payapl_ipn/2"

Comment: Are you sure about this? When I tried it this way it didn't work!

Comment: This is exactly what I was expecting but my notify_url only works for the first time and the rest of the payment had 'generic' url that  I put in for IPN url. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just noting that i am also seeing a possibly related problem for echecks where the later clearing ipn is not using the dynamic url that was specified in the originating transaction. First ipn advising pending payment goes to dynamic url
Second ipn advising cleared echeck goes to stored notification url not the dynamic url.

all other instant ipn's are fine and the 2nd ipn is received - but at the wrongurl - can see it in the logs.

any ideas appreciated - pending response from paypal.